# How do I use jQuery selectors to iterate through unordered lists independently?

Tags: jquery

I am working on a menu to display products for a cannabis dispensary. When we have a weighted item, such as flower, I would like users to be able to cycle through the list of weights (typically a gram, an eighth, a quarter, a half, and an ounce).

I have the functional idea working - iterating through a list and displaying one item at a time, but so far I had only gotten it working when the jQuery was selecting by ID.

Since there will be multiple products displayed at a single time these need to be operating independently of each other.

So the weight is being displayed like so:

```
<div class="prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left fa-lg"></i></div>
          <div class="p-0 text-center"><ul class='weightList' style="list-style-type:none;padding-left:0">
            <li>$15.00<br><div class="grey-text">Gram (1g)</div></li>
            <li>$50.00<br><div class="grey-text">Eighth (3.5g)</div></li>
            <li>$100.00<br><div class="grey-text">Quarter (7g)</div></li>
            <li>$200.00<br><div class="grey-text">Half Ounce (14g)</div></li>
            <li>$350.00<br><div class="grey-text">Ounce (28g)</div></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="p-0"><div class="next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-lg"></i>
</div>
</div>
```

My jQuery (so far - this is where I need the help) looks like this:

```
var $lis = $(".weightList li").hide();
$lis.slice(0, 1).show();
var size_li = $lis.length;
var x = 1,
    start = 0;

$('.next').click(function () {
  if (start + x < size_li) {
    $lis.slice(start, start + x).hide();
    start += x;
    $lis.slice(start, start + x).show();
  }
});
$('.prev').click(function () {
  if (start - x >= 0) {
    $lis.slice(start, start + x).hide();
    start -= x;
    $lis.slice(start, start + x).show();
  }
});
```

I had considered setting up the 'prev', 'next', and unordered list 'weightList' divs with IDs that contain the product id and then using the product id to determine which list to operate on, but I am not exactly sure how to set that up and it seems inefficient/ignoring some jQuery functionality.

I have set up a fiddle with what I have started with: https://jsfiddle.net/qy2hb7sd/

What you'll see first is that only the weight list under the first product is displayed, the second list is hidden (both should start at $15.00 with Gram (1g) below).

Second, you'll see that the previous and next arrows don't operate independently and that the weight lists under both products are acting as one list, with the list being displayed on the second product only after you have iterated through the first product (the price and weights jump between products).

There can be a couple of dozen products loaded on the page at one time (I went with 2 as a simple example).

I hope I have explained myself and my desired result, and I look forward to learning some good jQuery tricks.

Comment: Wrap them, then `$(".next").click(function() { $(this).closest(".wrapper").find("li");...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you need to do is keep tabs on each list for both the currently visible list item and the length of the list. When you click next, you need to see if you're at the end of the list and if so, reset the visibility to the first item. Conversely when you click previous, if you're on the first item you need to hide it and show the list item. The first line of jQuery below, `$(".weightList").find("li:gt(0)").hide();` hides all the weights except for the first one, in each list. The other two chunks of code control what happens when you click the prev/next buttons:

```js
$(".weightList").find("li:gt(0)").hide();
$('.next').click(function() {
  var vis_idx = $(this).parent().prev().find('li:visible').index();
  var list_length = $(this).parent().prev().find('li').length;
  if (vis_idx == list_length - 1) {
    $(this).parent().prev().find('li').eq(0).show();
    $(this).parent().prev().find('li').eq(list_length - 1).hide();
    vis_idx = 0;
  } else {
    $(this).parent().prev().find('li').eq(vis_idx).hide();
    $(this).parent().prev().find('li').eq(vis_idx + 1).show();
  }
})
$('.prev').click(function() {
  var vis_idx = $(this).parent().next().find('li:visible').index();
  var list_length = $(this).parent().next().find('li').length;
  if (vis_idx == 0) {
    $(this).parent().next().find('li').eq(list_length - 1).show();
    $(this).parent().next().find('li').eq(0).hide();
    vis_idx = 0;
  } else {
    $(this).parent().next().find('li').eq(vis_idx).hide();
    $(this).parent().next().find('li').eq(vis_idx - 1).show();
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">

    <!-- Card -->
    <div class="card card-ecommerce">


      <div class="card-body">

        <h5 class="card-title mb-1"><strong><a href="#" class="dark-grey-text">Head Master Kush Flower - RedBud Roots</a></strong></h5><span class="badge badge-pill badge-light mb-3">Flower</span>

        <div class="card-footer p-0 m-0">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between pt-4">
            <div class="p-0">
              <div class="prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left fa-lg"></i></div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-0 text-center">
              <ul class='weightList' style="list-style-type:none;padding-left:0">
                <li>$15.00<br>
                  <div class="grey-text">Gram (1g)</div>
                </li>
                <li>$50.00<br>
                  <div class="grey-text">Eighth (3.5g)</div>
                </li>
                <li>$100.00<br>
                  <div class="grey-text">Quarter (7g)</div>
                </li>
                <li>$200.00<br>
                  <div class="grey-text">Half Ounce (14g)</div>
                </li>
                <li>$350.00<br>
                  <div class="grey-text">Ounce (28g)</div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="p-0">
              <div class="next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-lg"></i></div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">

    <!-- Card -->
    <div class="card card-ecommerce">


      <div class="card-body">

        <h5 class="card-title mb-1"><strong><a href="#" class="dark-grey-text">High Life OG Kush Flower</a></strong></h5><span class="badge badge-pill badge-light mb-3">Flower</span>

        <div class="card-footer p-0 m-0">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between pt-4">
            <div class="p-0">
              <div class="prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left fa-lg"></i></div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-0 text-center">
              <ul class='weightList' style="list-style-type:none;padding-left:0">
                <li>$15.00<br>
                  <div class="grey-text">Gram (1g)</div>
                </li>
                <li>$50.00<br>
                  <div class="grey-text">Eighth (3.5g)</div>
                </li>
                <li>$100.00<br>
                  <div class="grey-text">Quarter (7g)</div>
                </li>
                <li>$200.00<br>
                  <div class="grey-text">Half Ounce (14g)</div>
                </li>
                <li>$350.00<br>
                  <div class="grey-text">Ounce (28g)</div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="p-0">
              <div class="next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-lg"></i></div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow that is a step beyond even what I was anticipating (I did not have my list cycling back to the first item from the last/last item from the first). Thank you! I'll be digesting this code and hopefully improve my jQuery understanding.

Comment: Let me know if you have questions on the code or if you want it to not loop when reaching the end/beginning